# Sqlite convert not supported date to timestamp in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have stored a date in sqlite database in this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format. Example `2019-12-11T14:30:00.000+0000`

I need to migrate database to convert this date to timestamp while migrating to Room. As this date format is not supported in sqlite I can't use sqlite functions to convert date to timestamp :(

How should I do it?

Comment: you want to convert `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` to `milliseconds`?

Comment: As mentioned by @Niraj you can convert date to milliseconds and save in long/number format in sqlite

Comment: Just drop the +0000 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
strftime(
  '%s', 
  substr('2019-12-11T14:30:00.000+0000', 1, 23)
)
```

will return the timestamp in seconds.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8aqtD1x2HAQiMxTQ8ZgWx/0).
Result:

```
1576074600
```